# ## There is an issue with node-fibers ##

Tags: node.js, npm

```
## There is an issue with `node-fibers` ##
`\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers\bin\win32-x64-57\fibers.node` is missing.
```

when Im running my node server with the command 'node server.js', I get this error out of the blue, I tried installing node fibers module, still no use, How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 56):

Try uninstalling and reinstalling fibers:

```
npm uninstall fibers
npm install fibers
```

Comment: Cannot uninstall even (on Mac), after a few min it says > fibers@4.0.3 install /Users/me/Documents/Dev/my-project/node_modules/fibers
> node build.js || nodejs build.js

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.

gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1. 

Seems after Catalina/Big Sur you have to reinstall xcode stuff: xcode-select --install

Comment: For me fibers\bin\win32-x64-88 folder was missing, uninstall followed by deleting the fibers folder and then installing fixed it.

Answer (score 20):

1. Go to (in your case) `\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers`
2. Run `npm install`

Comment: This is the best answer by far! The error should be a little clearer and suggest what to do in this case.

Answer (score 7):

If you aren't using **LTS** node version, try switching to LTS version, I just switch from `13.11.0` to `12.16.2(LTS)` and it just worked!

Answer (score 4):

The problem might be coming after upgrading your `Node.js`, especially `16+` due to [node-fibres](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers) update

*Update [April 13th, 2021] -- Fibers is not compatible with nodejs v16.0.0 or later. Unfortunately, v8 commit dacc2fee0f is a breaking change and workarounds are non-trivial.*

Downgrading to `Node.js` in version [`15.14.0`](https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.14.0/) fixes it.
After the operation running `rm -rf node_modules` & `npm install`/`yarn install` might be required.

Answer (score 0):

`npm i -g npm` was perhaps enough to fix this issue.

However, what I actually did to fix it was to reinstall `node` with `nvm` (Node Version Manager) and upgrade `npm` (Node Package Manager)

#### 1. Uninstall current version

```
apt remove node // debian or ubuntu
brew uninstall node // macos
```

#### 2. Install `nvm` (and follow given instructions!)

```
brew install nvm // macos
```

#### 3. Install `node` and `npm`

```
nvm install node
npm i -g npm
```